# Modify loaded input field value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, angularjs, input

I am using AngularJS as part of the MEAN stack. I have a model represented by `job`. `job.tag` is an attribute of the model represented by an array. The code below is the input field on a page used to edit the `job` attributes (the `job` has already been created with an array of various strings represented by `job.tag`).

```
<input data-ng-model="job.tag" type="text" id="tag" maxlength="50">
```

When the page used to edit the attributes is loaded - the input field is populated by a string representing the array which looks like "x,y,z" - when the array is converted into a string (the value which populates the text input field), commas are used to separate each element in the array. When the field is populated, how do I replace the commas with a whitespace, so the field displays "x y z"?

Comment: you could use a custom filter: `ng-model="job.tab | take-out-comma-filter`.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to realize is that your model is an array and your input is expecting a string.
By default, javascript converts an array into a string (via `array#toString`) with `array#join` dash separated.

More than that, If your try to change the view it will override your array model with the string from the input. This is how `ngModel` two-way-data-binding works.

Fortunately , `ngModel` is so awesome that it allows you to intercept the two-way-binding with your own formatters and parsers. The `$viewValue` and the $modelValue` can have different values, and the binding is fully configurable.

#### use [`ngModelController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController):

- `$formatters` to format / convert **model -> view**
- `$parsers` to format / convert **view -> model**

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HFjDHCHnBOStmYjk84ub?p=preview

**A simple directive:**

```
app.directive('array', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs,ngModel){

      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(str){
        return str.split(/\s+/)
      })

      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(arr){
        return arr.join(' ');
      });
    }
  }
})
```

**And the markup:**

```
<input data-ng-model="job.tag" 
       type="text" 
       id="tag"
       data-array
       maxlength="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the javascript string object utility functions such as replace()?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: yes...I know how replace works - and that is what I am using to substitute, I just don't know how to implement it.